# Table search and pagination - jquery light plugin

Tags: jquery, search, pagination

I need to implement pagination and search in my table listing. I am not interested to use JQ table sorter or Data table because its size is big.

Any one can advice me a plugin/code which satisfy my requirement.

NB : Not using DB

Thanks

Comment: Still probably overkill, but much smaller than datatables: http://wootapa-watable.appspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Editable Grid](http://www.editablegrid.net/page/en/1/home.html) is a very good open source JavaScript library aimed at turning tables into fully editable components.

- [Features](http://www.editablegrid.net/page/en/2/features.html)
- [Demos](http://www.editablegrid.net/page/en/6/demos.html)

Comment: Here we need PHP... I am not using PHP as server script

Comment: Editable Grid isn't exactly light weight, either.